# Assignment to constant variable exception

Tags: javascript, exception, google-chrome-extension, automation

I am getting the following exception: Value currently is [object Object]
popup.html:1 Error handling response: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at chrome-extension://....../popup.js:19:18
Trying to get the input from my Chrome extension and using it in here...

```
const settings =    {
                        name: "",
                        email: "",
                        tel: "",
                        cc_number: "",
                        cc_exp: "",
                        cc_csc: "",
                        address_line1: "",
                        address_level2: "",
                        address_level1: "",
                        postal_code: ""
                    }


function getSettingsfromStorage() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['settings'], function(result) {
        console.log('im getter');
        console.log('Value currently is ' + result); //Exception
        settings = result; //Exception
    });
}

function saveSettingstoStorage() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({'settings': settings}, function() {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + settings);
    });
}

function getSettingsfromPopup() {
    for(let setting in settings) {
        console.log(setting);
        settings.setting = document.getElementById(setting).value;
        console.log(setting);
    }
}

function saveSettingstoPopup() {
    for(let setting in settings) {
        console.log(setting);
        if(document.getElementById(setting)) {
            document.getElementById(setting).value = settings.setting;
        }
        console.log(setting);
    } 
}

async function getFromPopUpAndSaveToStorage() {
    await getSettingsfromPopup();
    saveSettingstoStorage();
}

async function getFromStorageAndSaveToSettings() {
    await getSettingsfromStorage();
    saveSettingstoPopup();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    //settings.fullName = document.getElementById(name).value;
    getFromStorageAndSaveToSettings();
    document.getElementById("saveButton").addEventListener("click", getFromPopUpAndSaveToStorage());
})
```

Comment: when a variable is declared as `const`, you can't reassign it later (settings is const, so you get an error when you do `settings = result`)

Comment: *The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

You can't reassign a variable which declared as `const`. If it is an object, you can change its properties. If it is an array, you can change its values, but still you can't reassign it.